# Obtaining JSoup Elements in certain order

Tags: java, jsoup

In one `<div>` element I have three types of elements (among the others):

- `<span class="some_name_1">`
- `<div class="some_name_2">`
- `<p>`

The problem is that I don't know how their number and the order they're in. So what I would need is to have all of these elements shown above in some kind of array so I could iterate over them.

I am quite new to JSoup - how could I achieve such thing? The order is crucial for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, you need to iterate on elements? This is simple.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
         Element div = doc.select("div").first(); //here you get your parent div
         for (Element element : div.children()) {
            //Here you can acccess all childs of your div
        }
```

Comment: I meant to iterate only on these three types of elements, not all children. But, as it usually is, one thinks how to solve a problem, posts question on stackoverflow and few moments later finds the solution on his own. All I needed was proper choice of selectors and it works :)

Comment: Ok, I thought, you can itarate on every child, check it and decide wheter to do with it.

Comment: @AleksanderHulist maybe you close a question?